# pyttsx3 - stuck in loop open, through articles

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    news = requests.get(url).text
    news_dict = json.loads(news)
    arts = news_dict['articles'][:2]
    for article in arts:
        engine = init()
        text = " ".join([article["description"] + "\n\n\n\n\n\n" + "pausing for the next article" + "\n\n\n\n\n\n" for article in arts])
        engine.setProperty('rate', 185)
        engine.say(text)
        engine.runAndWait()
    engine.endLoop()
    engine.say("finished")
    engine.runAndWait()
    response = make_response(b'')
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'audio/mpeg'
    return response
```

don't yell at me for the artificial \n delays :-), i could not get this to loop/start/end correctly, that said - still have an error:

raise RuntimeError('run loop already started')
RuntimeError: run loop already started

i've been through a ton of examples, iterations with no success.

This ended up working:

def speak_text(text):
engine = pyttsx3.init()
try:
engine.endLoop()
del engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()
except:
pass
engine.startLoop()
engine.setProperty('rate', 185)
engine.say(text)

Comment: i was scraping news articles and joining [5] for a readout [aka text to speech].  the challenge was i was getting loop errors on subsequent requests to app. I ultimately as stated by the answer kill the engine, end the loop, start the engine, and not use runandwait. there was no clear documentation on external loop() in this use-case. I'm still facing the problem of returning an 'end' or 'complete' back to the browser

Answer (score 0):

This setup seemed to do it for me!

```
def speak_text(text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    try:
        engine.endLoop()
        del engine
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
    except:
        pass
        engine.startLoop()
        engine.setProperty('rate', 185)
        engine.say(text)
```